# How to detect mouse movement over node while button is pressed?

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

**Problem**

You can add an event listener to a node which detects mouse movement over it. This doesn't work if a mouse button was pressed before you moved over the node.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to detect mouse movement while the button is pressed? So far I've only found a solution by using the [MOUSE_DRAGGED](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_DRAGGED) event and then instead of using getSource() using getPickResult() and evaluating the [PickResult](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/PickResult.html) data.

Here's the code including Uluk's solution. The old and new solution are switchable via the useNewVersion (Uluk's version) boolean:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.PickResult;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    boolean useNewVersion= true;

    int rows = 10;
    int columns = 20;
    double width = 1024;
    double height = 768;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

            // create grid
            Grid grid = new Grid( columns, rows, width, height);

            MouseGestures mg = new MouseGestures();

            // fill grid
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {

                    Cell cell = new Cell(column, row);

                    mg.makePaintable(cell);

                    grid.add(cell, column, row);
                }
            }

            root.setCenter(grid);

            // create scene and stage
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class Grid extends Pane {

        int rows;
        int columns;

        double width;
        double height;

        Cell[][] cells;

        public Grid( int columns, int rows, double width, double height) {

            this.columns = columns;
            this.rows = rows;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;

            cells = new Cell[rows][columns];

        }

        /**
         * Add cell to array and to the UI.
         */
        public void add(Cell cell, int column, int row) {

            cells[row][column] = cell;

            double w = width / columns;
            double h = height / rows;
            double x = w * column;
            double y = h * row;

            cell.setLayoutX(x);
            cell.setLayoutY(y);
            cell.setPrefWidth(w);
            cell.setPrefHeight(h);

            getChildren().add(cell);

        }

    }

    private class Cell extends StackPane {

        int column;
        int row;

        public Cell(int column, int row) {

            this.column = column;
            this.row = row;

            getStyleClass().add("cell");

            Label label = new Label(this.toString());

            getChildren().add(label);
        }

        public void highlight() {
            getStyleClass().add("cell-highlight");
        }

        public void unhighlight() {
            getStyleClass().remove("cell-highlight");
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.column + "/" + this.row;
        }
    }

    public class MouseGestures {

        public void makePaintable( Node node) {

            if( useNewVersion) {

                node.setOnMousePressed( onMousePressedEventHandler);
                node.setOnDragDetected( onDragDetectedEventHandler);
                node.setOnMouseDragEntered( onMouseDragEnteredEventHandler);

            } else {

                node.setOnMousePressed( onMousePressedEventHandler);
                node.setOnMouseDragged( onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
                node.setOnMouseReleased( onMouseReleasedEventHandler);

            }

        }

        /* old version */

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = event -> {

            Cell cell = (Cell) event.getSource();

            if( event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                cell.highlight();
            } else if( event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                cell.unhighlight();
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = event -> {

            PickResult pickResult = event.getPickResult();
            Node node = pickResult.getIntersectedNode();

            if( node instanceof Cell) {

                Cell cell = (Cell) node;

                if( event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    cell.highlight();
                } else if( event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    cell.unhighlight();
                }       

            }

        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = event -> {
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onDragDetectedEventHandler = event -> {

            Cell cell = (Cell) event.getSource();
            cell.startFullDrag();

        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDragEnteredEventHandler = event -> {

            Cell cell = (Cell) event.getSource();

            if( event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                cell.highlight();
            } else if( event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                cell.unhighlight();
            }       

        };

    }

}
```

In the end you should be able to paint via primary mouse button and erase the paint via secondary mouse button:

[image]

Comment: Is the `node` different from the `Button`? I don't exactly get your question. Are you trying to read mouse movement on the same Button when it is pressed?

Comment: The node which handles the initial DRAG_DETECTED event should invoke sourceNode.startFullDrag(), then the target node will able to handle MOUSE_DRAG_OVER events with targetNode.setOnMouseDragOver() method.

Comment: @ItachiUchia: I meant mouse button. I changed it and added code including Uluk's version. I needed it for the A* algorithm I posted yesterday, so that it's easier to paint different kinds of walls via simple mouse drag (while having primary button down). It worked, but using PickResult felt strange.

Comment: @Uluk Biy: Thanks a lot, it works. I applied it to the source code above. Can you post it as an answer please so that I can accept it and close the question?

Comment: @Roland, to avoid unnecessary handler invokings it is better to register MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED instead of MOUSE_DRAG_OVER in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (source) node which handles the initial `DRAG_DETECTED` event should invoke `sourceNode.startFullDrag()`, then the target node will able to handle one of [MouseDragEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseDragEvent.html)s, for instance `MOUSE_DRAG_OVER` or `MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED` event with respective `targetNode.setOn<MouseDragEvent>()` method.

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to add an event filter to the scene which enables the sourceNode.startFullDrag(). This will work even if you start dragging the mouse outside of your canvas (if you want any space without nodes in your application).

Like this:

```
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED , new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        scene.startFullDrag();
    }
});
```

And then you could:

```
node.setOnMouseDragEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        led.setOn(true);
    } 
});
```