# Java - Method Undefined in Eclipse

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have a 3 class java application, I am trying to create a simple game using JavaFX.  In My GameCore class I am trying to create an instance of gameGrid. but when I use "grid = new gameGrid(int, int, int, int);" eclipse tells me gameGrid is undefined and suggests I create the method, when I do as eclipse asks, it places a private method gameGrid in my gameCore class, but gameGrid is supposed to be the constructor for gameGrid.class. I have already restarted the project and cleaned the project to no avail.

```
public class gameCore {

    gameGrid grid;

    public gameCore(){
        getGrid();
    }

    public void getGrid(){
        grid = gameGrid(32, 32, 10, 10); //Error is here, underlining "gameGrid"
//Also using gameGrid.gameGrid(32,32,10,10); does not work either, still says its undefined

/*
This is the code that Eclipse wants to place when I let it fix the error, and it places this code in this class.
private gameGrid gameGrid(int i, int j, int k, int l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
*/

    }

}
```

---

```
public class gameGrid {

    protected int[][] grid;
    protected int tileWidth;
    protected int tileHeight;

    public gameGrid(int tileWidth, int tileHeight, int horizTileCount, int vertTileCount){
        //Create Grid Object

        grid = new int[vertTileCount][];
        for(int y = 0; y < vertTileCount; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < horizTileCount; x++){
                grid[y] = new int[horizTileCount];
            }
        }

        this.tileWidth = tileWidth;
        this.tileHeight = tileHeight;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class gameGUI extends Application {

    Dimension screenDimensions = new Dimension(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(sp, screenDimensions.width, screenDimensions.height);

        sp.getChildren().add(c);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        gameCore game = new gameCore();



        stage.show();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is "new" for instantiation, i. e. you need to write

```
grid = new gameGrid(32, 32, 10, 10);
```

In Java classes start with uppercase character, you should [read the guidelines](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2.2-class-names).

*In case you want to see a grid being done in JavaFX with java nodes instead of a canvas, you can look at [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117351/how-to-detect-mouse-movement-over-node-while-button-is-pressed) of the question I asked recently.*

Comment: Thanks! This solved it, Don't know how I missed that, Probably need to get some sleep... Also I renamed my classes, I knew that but haven't done a serious java program in a while, thanks for the reminder...